# RuntimeError: threads can only be started once Python Tkinter webserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, webserver, python-multithreading

I am trying to create a webserver in python which can be started and stopped using a tkinter GUI. In tkinter I have a button which will call start() and a button that will call stop().  Initially everything works fine, the server starts when I click the button and it also stops when I click the stop button. When I try to restart the server again using the start button, I get a runtime error

RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

I believe it has something to do with the fact that I have already initialized threading in my **init**, and I can not figure out how to get this to work.

I have read through the threading docs multiple times, but I am struggling to understand it entirely.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
import threading
import socketserver
import http.server
import os


class WebServer(object):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
        self.server = socketserver.TCPServer((self.host, self.port), self.handler)
        socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever, name="Server_Thread")
        self.server_thread.setDaemon(True)

    def start(self):
        web_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'www')
        os.chdir(web_dir)
        self.server_thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        os.chdir('..')
        self.server.shutdown()
        self.server.server_close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the python documentation [states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start), the `start` method of the `Thread` object can only be called once.

In your case, you can create new instance of the Thread object in the `start` method:

```
def start(self):
    web_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'www')
    os.chdir(web_dir)
    self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever, name="Server_Thread")
    self.server_thread.start()
```

In addition you also may clean the reference to the thread in `stop` method:

```
self.server_thread = None
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense now.