# Why do locally-started threads not terminate at the end of each iteration?

Tags: python, multithreading

According to what is suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582467/runtimeerror-threads-can-only-be-started-once-python-tkinter-webserver), to get rid of `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once` , I have tried to start each thread when its corresponding object is created (instead of directly starting them in the main body of the code). The final purpose is that when each iteration of the main code is finished, the threads which are running in it also terminate. To start all threads **simultaneously**, I consider

```
for obj in objects:
    obj.launch_obj(q)
```

in the following snippet.

```
import random
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

objects = []
threads = []

def generate_id():
    My_class.ID +=1
    return My_class.ID

def reset_id():
    My_class.ID = 0

class My_class(object):

    ID = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = generate_id()
        objects.append(self)

    def launch_obj(self, q):
        thread = Thread(target=do, args=(q,self.id,))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

epochs = 4

success = [0 for x in range(epochs)]

def do(q, id):
    temp = q.get()
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        temp += 1
    print("\t object: {0} -> temp: {1}".format(id, temp))
    return q.put(temp)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("iteration: {0}".format(epoch+1))
    temp = 0
    q = Queue()
    q.put(temp)
    obj1 = My_class()
    obj2 = My_class()

    for obj in objects:
        obj.launch_obj(q)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    temp = q.get(temp)

    success[epoch] = temp

    reset_id()
```

However, The output reads like

```
iteration: 1
     object: 1 -> temp: 0
     object: 2 -> temp: 0
iteration: 2
     object: 1 -> temp: 0
     object: 2 -> temp: 0
     object: 1 -> temp: 1
     object: 2 -> temp: 2
iteration: 3
     object: 1 -> temp: 0
     object: 2 -> temp: 1
     object: 1 -> temp: 2
     object: 2 -> temp: 3
     object: 1 -> temp: 3
     object: 2 -> temp: 3
iteration: 4
     object: 1 -> temp: 0
     object: 2 -> temp: 1
     object: 1 -> temp: 1
     object: 2 -> temp: 2
     object: 1 -> temp: 3
     object: 2 -> temp: 4
     object: 1 -> temp: 4
     object: 2 -> temp: 4
```

in which the threads of each iteration are not killed at the end of that iteration. On the other hand, if I start the threads individually, like

```
obj1.launch_obj(q)
obj2.launch_obj(q)
```

then, the output's form apparently becomes similar to what I expect.

```
iteration: 1
     object: 1 -> temp: 0
     object: 2 -> temp: 1
iteration: 2
     object: 1 -> temp: 1
     object: 2 -> temp: 1
iteration: 3
     object: 1 -> temp: 1
     object: 2 -> temp: 1
iteration: 4
     object: 1 -> temp: 1
     object: 2 -> temp: 1
```

So, I have the following two related questions.

1- What is the difference between starting threads in a loop vs. doing it sequentially?

2- How may one fix the behavior of the first snippet (in which threads are started in a loop) such that the threads of each iteration are terminated at the end of that iteration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, the problem is how you keep track of your objects.

For each iteration, you are only interested in the objects created in that iteration, yes? Then, there is no reason to have that list defined globally. So, move `objects = []` to inside the for loop. That way it will be nice and empty for each iteration.

Of course, then the class can't add itself to the list in the constructor (unless you pass `objects` to the constructor). But to be honest, you should avoid doing that. Now we have this:

```py
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("iteration: {0}".format(epoch+1))
    objects = []

    ...

    objects.append(My_class())
    objects.append(My_class())

    ...

    reset_id()
```

In general, you need to think about where your logic should be. A class should take care of itself and not have to depend on any outside objects or methods. To that end, the 'generate_id' and 'reset_id' methods should also move to inside the class definition. Maybe like this?

```py
import random
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

class My_class(object):

    ID = 0

    @classmethod
    def generate_id(cls):
        cls.ID +=1
        return cls.ID

    @classmethod
    def reset_id(cls):
        cls.ID = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = My_class.generate_id()

    def launch_obj(self, q):
        thread = Thread(target=do, args=(q,self.id,))
        thread.start()

        return thread

epochs = 4

success = [0 for x in range(epochs)]

def do(q, id):
    temp = q.get()
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        temp += 1
    print("\t object: {0} -> temp: {1}".format(id, temp))
    return q.put(temp)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("iteration: {0}".format(epoch+1))

    objects = []
    threads = []

    temp = 0
    q = Queue()
    q.put(temp)
    objects.append(My_class())
    objects.append(My_class())

    for obj in objects:
        threads.append(obj.launch_obj(q))

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    temp = q.get(temp)

    success[epoch] = temp

    My_class.reset_id()
```

Now, it's perfectly reasonable to have the class add itself to the objects list for some use cases. One case could be that it needs to keep track of it's siblings. But then you need to be explicit about it, so that it's easy for future you or a fellow developer to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You've misdiagnosed your bug. This has nothing to do with threads not terminating.

Your `objects` list gets more and more objects in it on each iteration of the `for epoch in range(epochs)` loop, and on each iteration, you start a new thread for *every object* in the list. That unexpected output on later iterations isn't from the old threads still lingering for some reason. It's from new threads you never should have started.

Trying to add objects to a global registry in `__init__` is a bad idea that leads to bugs like this. Manage your data structures explicitly - it makes it a lot easier to keep track of what objects are relevant to what code, it helps avoid keeping objects around forever, and it makes using multiple data structures much easier.

Comment: But if what you noted were the problem, starting threads successively would have been problematic, as well, because the way those lists in the code are managed is identical in both cases. However, this issue only rises when one starts threads in a loop.

Comment: @Roboticist: You didn't start threads for every object when you did it manually. You only started threads for the objects created on the most recent iteration.

Comment: I see. Do you think the following naive work-around may work? In each iteration, I pick the last-two items of the objects (i.e., the most two recent ones) and only start threads for them.

Comment: @Roboticist: Changing how you populate and manage your `objects` list would make things much more manageable.

Comment: I tried that one, but this formulation is the only one according to which I could manage to get rid of `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`. Thanks for your constructive hints, anyway.